# Quarto website - make template for javascript button ("show answer")

Tags: javascript, r, r-markdown, quarto

I am making a website with Quarto. I can add Javascript and HTML code in the quarto document (.qmd file). I am not well-versed in Javascript, but found the following:

```
<button class="show-answer" onclick="showAnswer('answer1')"> Show answer</button>
<p id="answer1" style="display: none;">Secret answer 1</p>

<button class="show-answer" onclick="showAnswer('answer2')"> Show answer</button>
<p id="answer2" style="display: none;">Secret answer 2</p>

<script>
function showAnswer(answerId) {
  var answer = document.getElementById(answerId);
  if (answer.style.display === "none") {
    answer.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    answer.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

This works. The webpage, however, requires this button many times. Is it possible to make some kind of template, so I can write in the Quarto document (for example)

```
[answer] Secret answer [/answer]
```

The Javascript also seems to require some id, e.g. `id="answer1"`. Is it possible to automate this id generation if I am using a template?

Comment: Why not try [Collapsible Callout Blocks](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/callouts.html)?

Comment: I am trying to imitate, indeed, this functionality. However, sometimes the answer to the webexercise is just a number (numeric solutions). The callout block takes up too much space to hide a simple number. That's why I wanted a "smaller" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a JS function that will replace a div element (created with pandoc divs `::: {.class}`) with answers or a span element (created with pandoc spans `[]{.class}`) with answers with the structure below,

```
<button class="show-answer" onclick="showAnswer('answer1')"> Show answer</button>
<p id="answer1" style="display: none;">Secret answer 1</p>
```

### Full Reprex

**add-answer-button.html**

```
<script>
  
  function addAnswerWithButton(answerClass, buttonText, answerText) {
    
    const divElement = document.querySelector(`.${answerClass}`);
    const randomId = "answer-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
  
    // Create the new button element
    const buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
    buttonElement.className = "show-answer";
    buttonElement.textContent = buttonText;
    buttonElement.onclick = function() {
      showAnswer(randomId);
    };
  
    // Create the new answer element
    const answerElement = document.createElement("p");
    answerElement.id = randomId;
    answerElement.style.display = "none";
    answerElement.innerHTML = answerText;
  
    // Replace the div element with the new button and answer elements
    divElement.parentNode.replaceChild(buttonElement, divElement);
    buttonElement.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", answerElement);
  }
  
  function showAnswer(answerId) {
    var answer = document.getElementById(answerId);
    if (answer.style.display === "none") {
      answer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      answer.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function addAnswerButton() {
    var answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer")
    answers.forEach(e => {
      addAnswerWithButton("answer", " Show Answer", e.innerHTML);
    });
  }
  
  window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    addAnswerButton();
  });
</script>
```

**test.qmd**

```
---
title: Answer Button
format: html
include-in-header: add-answer-button.html
---

## Exercise

Question1: What is 1 + 1? [Answer: 2]{.answer}

Question2: Some question? 

[This is some answer to question 2]{.answer}


Question3: Some more question? 

::: {.answer}

This is some answer to question 3

:::
```

Here you can write answers within squares bracket and then assign the `.answer` class to it (e.g. `[some answer]{.answer}` and it will be replaced with a button (See the rendered output below), and also you can write the answers wrapped within the `:::` and assign the class `.answer` to the div.

---

[image: answers with button]

Comment: Is there a way to support LaTeX in the answer field? Things like "[$\sqrt{x}$]{.answer}" are not rendered.

Comment: Okay, I have updated `add-answer-button.html` file. Try with that!